# How to speed up build downloads for global teams?

Tags: build, download, continuous-integration, scalability, scaling

I am working with a globally distributed development team that has to download builds of our software across geographies and oceans. Our build output is GBs in size and takes a while for developers in China to acquire the content from our servers in the US.

What can my team do to help make this process faster? I have some ideas (mirrors, only downloading delta changes, P2P), but would love some insight into how other teams have solved this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is using a proxy server. TFS does it very well with out-of-the-box proxy service.

[image: TFS Proxy]

You can consider publishing your artifacts on mirrored FTP or use a 3rd party proxy solution such as
[WinGate](http://www.wingate.com/).

Comment: Marking this answer as the accepted solution, but with the caveat for future users that not all teams use Team Foundation Server for their work. However, the idea of the proxy server sounds like the right solution to me.